# Move title box to the right side of tcbtheorem

Tags: formatting, tcolorbox, theorems

I have the following document but would like the title ('c' is a placeholder) to be on the right hand side of the tcbtheorem only (NOT also next to the Example 1.2:). I'd also like the c on the right hand side to be in a gray box with an orange outline just the same as "Example 1.1" etc. When there is no title, there should be no gray box on the right. How do I do this?

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1.75cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,microtype}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{skins}

\makeatletter

% THEOREM
\newtcbtheorem[auto counter,number within=section]{theorem}{Theorem}%
{enhanced,
frame empty,
interior empty,
coltitle=black,
boxsep=0pt, % Set boxsep to 0pt to remove inner padding
fonttitle=\bfseries,colbacktitle=cyan!15!white,
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=12pt,yshift=-1pt/2-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,bottom=3pt,top=3pt}, % Adjust boxsep here as well
varwidth boxed title}{thm}

% LEMMA
\newtcbtheorem[use counter from=theorem, number within=section]{lemma}{Exam\smash{p}le}%
{enhanced,
breakable,
frame empty,
interior empty,
colframe=orange!50!white, 
coltitle=black,
boxsep=0pt, % Set boxsep to 0pt to remove inner padding
overlay={\node[
left, 
text=black,
anchor=east,
font=\bfseries] 
at (frame.north east) {#2};},
attach boxed title to top left={xshift=12pt,yshift=-1pt/2-\tcboxedtitleheight/2},
boxed title style={boxrule=1pt, boxsep=0pt,left=3pt,right=3pt,bottom=3pt,top=3pt}, % Adjust boxsep here as well
varwidth boxed title}{thm}

\makeatother

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}

    \section{First Section}


        \begin{lemma}{}{}
            lemma
        \end{lemma}
    
        \begin{lemma}{c}{}
            Some text
        \end{lemma}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: would you like to add a hand sketch of the desired output